# Comparing only the time component of Date

Tags: java, date

Consider the following code to only determine if the time component of one Date object is before the time component of another Date object:

```
private boolean validStartStopTime( Date start, Date stop ) {
  Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar stopCal = Calendar.getInstance();

  startCal.clear();
  stopCal.clear();

  startCal.setTime( start );
  stopCal.setTime( stop );

  startCal.set( Calendar.YEAR, 2011 );
  stopCal.set( Calendar.YEAR, 2011 );
  startCal.set( Calendar.MONTH, 1 );
  stopCal.set( Calendar.MONTH, 1 );
  startCal.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1 );
  stopCal.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1 );

  return startCal.before( stopCal );
}
```

Would this insure that time comparison is correct? Is there a better alternative (**Joda is not an option**)? I believe that this is equivalent to setting the `Calendar` objects to current date/time and manually copying over the hour, minutes, and milliseconds component. You can assume that timezone are the same.

EDIT: To clarify what I mean by comparing only the time component of a `Date` object. I mean that when looking specifically at the time portion, the start time is before the stop time. The date portion is ABSOLUTELY irrelevant (in that start="Jan 2 20011 10AM" and end="Jan 1 2011 11AM" is perfectly fine), if I had a choice I'd simply use something that contained just the time but a `Date` object is what I'm given. I'd like to not write a sequence of if-else which is why I have the approach above but I welcome a cleaner/better approach.

Comment: No need to set the year, month, etc.. since getInstance() is returning a Calendar object set to "now".  However to ensure they are identical I would change: stopCal = (Calendar)startCal.clone();  Otherwise I don't see why this would not work.

Comment: I agree with @mirswith while this may work it accentuates how confusing java's time implementation is and could be cleaned up by only using the clone and the setTimes (which copy over all fields). Additionally, using clear is dangerous as Calendar must set those dirty fields to something prior to returning the answer of before().

Comment: Is there any way to use Joda?

Comment: To clarify, if the start time is at 10:00 PM (22:00) on day 1, and the end time is at 2:00 AM (2:00) on day 2, the start/stop is invalid?

Comment: @chrislovecnm: Joda technically is an option but I'd rather not use it for just one part of the entire project but rather use it throughout in another iteration.

Comment: @ty1824: only the time part of a date is relevant, so in your example that would be invalid since start=10PM is after end=2AM.

Comment: @nevets1219 I recommend using it now, you do not have to worry about ANY of this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code should work fine.  You could also format just the time components in a zero-based string notation and compare them lexicographically:

```
public static boolean timeIsBefore(Date d1, Date d2) {
  DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
  return f.format(d1).compareTo(f.format(d2)) < 0;
}
```

**[Edit]**

This is assuming that the dates have the same timezone offset.  If not you'll have to adjust them manually beforehand (or as part of this function).

Answer (score 3):

There are 86,400,000 milliseconds in a day, why not just use that to figure it out?
You could just mod timeInMilliseconds with that number and compare the results.

Comment: Thanks Karl, I love a good mathematical solution to a problem.

Comment: There are 86,400,000 milliseconds in **most** days. You don't want to start down the road of converting dates and times yourself.

Comment: This won't work, because depending on the timezone, the epoch could represent 23:00 or 1:00 (for example), and depending on the daylight saving time, two dates separated by 86,400,000 millis could have a different time.

Comment: The question was just to compare the time component of 2 date/calendar objects. Sure there are daylight saving adjustments and even a second adjustment in some years but my implication the Date or Calendar would have taken that into account in the time and time comparison would still be valid. But yes, I wouldn't rely on this in mission critical situations. In MISYS a core banking system they use Julian dates as there are no leap days etc in them, you could try that http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0506.html

Comment: Perhaps, however, even in different timezones if you were comparing the time component the answer would be correct, the question did not specify anything regarding timezone adjustment. **Heck, the question actually says that we can assume the timezones are the same**

Comment: @Ali: suppose that next night at 3AM, we go back to 2AM because of DST. Now add 24 hours and 30 minutes to today at 3AM. Normally it would lead to a a date with 3:30AM. But today, because of DST, it's not the case: it will lead to 2:30AM. And your comparison is thus not correct.

Comment: `The question was just to compare the time component of 2 date/calendar objects.` - which you cannot do unless you're using the correct time component, which *requires* accounting for timezones.

Comment: yes, if the 2ice a year adjustment is a problem, then I would probably convert date objects to julian date and time and do the same. I mentioned that above.